# Is Initialization On Demand Holder idiom thread safe without a final modifier

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, immutability, idioms

I have a hunch that using the holder idiom without declaring the holder field as final is not thread safe (due to the way immutability works in Java). Can somebody confirm this (hopefully with some sources)?

```
public class Something {
    private long answer = 1;

    private Something() {
         answer += 10;
         answer += 10;
    }

    public int getAnswer() {
      return answer;
    }

    private static class LazyHolder {
        // notice no final
        private static Something INSTANCE = new Something();
    }

    public static Something getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

EDIT: I definitely want sourced statements, not just assertions like "it works" -- please explain/prove it's safe

EDIT2: A little modification to make my point more clear - can I be sure that the getAnswer() method will return 21 regardless of calling thread?

Comment: It's completely threadsafe, final or not.

Comment: sources for this assertion?

Comment: Java Memory Model - I'll answer... oops, too late: @assylias has done it for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [class initialization procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) guarantees that if a static field's value is set using a static initializer (i.e. `static variable = someValue;`) that value is visible to all threads:

> 10 - If the execution of the initializers completes normally, then ***acquire LC, label the Class object for C as fully initialized, notify all waiting threads, release LC***, and complete this procedure normally.

---

Regarding your edit, let's imagine a situation with two threads T1 and T2, executing in that order from a wall clock's perspective:

- T1: `Something s = Something.getInstance();`
- T2: `Something s = Something.getInstance(); i = s.getAnswer();`

Then you have:

- T1 acquire LC, T1 run `Something INSTANCE = new Something();`, which initialises `answer`, T1 release LC
- T2 tries to acquire LC, but already locked by T1 => waits. When T1 releases LC, T2 acquire LC, reads `INSTANCE` then reads `answer`.

So you can see that you have a proper happens-before relationship between the write and the read to `answer`, thanks to the `LC` lock.

Comment: @edit - this was clear to me after you answered, but thanks for the example anyway

Comment: @assylias, I'm not sure whether here is not possible scenario when `s`(reference) is published but `answer` is not initialized yet, or I'm wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is thread-safe for sure, but is mutable. So anyone who gets it may assign it to something else. And that is first thing to worry about (even before considering thread-safety).

Comment: Only, nobody outside the `Something` class *can* get it.

Comment: Yes, that's true +1 from me. So actually the mutability problem can occur only in methods of the Something class. But I think it is thread-safe because of the class loading being synchronized anyway (no matter final or not final).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - surely anybody can use the public method to get the instance, what do you mean?

Comment: @JakubBochenski I mean *assign* it.

Comment: @JakubBochenski Nobody can write `Something.LazyHolder.INSTANCE = new Something();` because `INSTANCE` is private.

Comment: @peter.petrov - you can also modify the static field with reflection

Comment: @JakubBochenski Marko means nobody outside of Something can reassign it like "Something.LazyHolder.INSTANCE = x" where x is another object.

Comment: @JakubBochenski You can modify a `private static final` field using reflection just as well (unless it's a compile-time constant).

Comment: @JakubBochenski We don't talk reflection here :), if we add this to to the cake, things get different as you can compromise lots of things through reflection.

Comment: @peter.petrov About thread-safety, you are right. Class initialization is synchronized so there's a *happens-before* relation between the end of initialization and the point in code which caused the init to happen.