# Singleton using "Initialization-on-demand holder idiom"

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

This question is related to Initialization On Demand Holder idiom. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20995091/2796922) it IS thread safe without a final modifier.

I hope this is not a dumb question.

I have a configuration singleton that uses `org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration`. Well In fact I have three and it can be increased later.

It has a default file name to get the configuration from.

I need to be able to define a new configuration file name later on and re-create the instance using it.

When I was using a non Thread-Safe singleton, I used to set the new file name and then reset the variable containing the instance to null, and that was it. The next time the configuration was used, it was automatically initialized using the new configuration file name.

I can't do it that way using "Initialization-on-demand holder idiom" anymore, since I can't "disappear" the holder class. (right?)

I tried to re-assign the static variable containing the instance, but apparently it's not working.

This is a common ancestor for the configuration classes:

```
public class ConfiguracionBase {
    protected static String configFileName = "config.xml";

    protected static void abreConfiguracion(XMLConfiguration XMLConfig) throws ConfigurationException {
        //Should be placed in the same directory as this application.
        boolean exists = (new File(configFileName)).exists();
...
        if (exists) {
            try {
                XMLConfig = new XMLConfiguration(configFileName);
            } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
                if (e.getMessage().startsWith("Unable to load the configuration")) {
                    logger.fatal("IMPOSIBLE CONTINUAR: "+e.getMessage()+" ["+configFileName+"]",e);
                    StrUtil.writeToSimpleLog(Level.FATAL , "IMPOSIBLE CONTINUAR: "+e.getMessage()+" ["+configFileName+"]");
                    System.exit(Grales.EXIT_STATUS_ERROR_EN_CONFIGURACION);
                } else {
                    throw e; 
                }
            }

            XMLConfig.setThrowExceptionOnMissing(Boolean.TRUE);

...


    protected String getStringValue( [... some params ...] , XMLConfiguration XMLConfig) {

...

    protected int getIntValue( [... some params ...] , XMLConfiguration XMLConfig) {

...
```

This is one of my configuration classes:

```
public class Configuracion extends ConfiguracionBase {


    private static class ConfiguracionHolder {
        protected static Configuracion config = new Configuracion();
        protected static XMLConfiguration XMLConfig = null;

        private ConfiguracionHolder() throws ConfigurationException {
            abreConfiguracion(XMLConfig);
        }

    }

    private Configuracion() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }

    public static Configuracion getInstance() throws ConfigurationException {
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", ConfiguracionHolder.config.getTimezoneCFD());
        return ConfiguracionHolder.config;
    }

    public static void setConfigFileName(String configFileName) {
        ConfiguracionBase.configFileName = configFileName;
        ConfiguracionHolder.config = new Configuracion();
    }

...
```

My config.xml (default config) has a money format like this: `$,0.00000000;$(,0.00000000)`

My new configAbsoluteFileName has a money format like this: `\,0.00000000;-\,0.00000000`

When I start my application, I do something like this:

```
    Configuracion.setConfigFileName(configAbsoluteFileName);
```

I added a test method that does:

```
                    logger.debug("************ config file name: " + Configuracion.getConfigFileName() + " *******************");
                    logger.debug("************ money format: " + Configuracion.getInstance().getFormatoDineroHumanos() + " *******************");
```

And even If the file name is the new one, the format is the old one.

I think it may be happening because the configuration file name variable is defined in the ConfiguracionBase, and not inside my holder "sub" class.

But I didn't want to repeat the initialization in every configuration singleton.

Hope it's clear and someone can shed some light on it.

Thank you all.

---

EDIT 1: 
replaced

```
    public static void setConfigFileName(String configFileName) {
        ConfiguracionBase.configFileName = configFileName;
        ConfiguracionHolder.config = new Configuracion();
    }
```

for

```
    public static void setConfigFileName(String configFileName) {
        Configuracion.configFileName = configFileName;
        ConfiguracionHolder.config = new Configuracion();
    }i
```

But nothing changed

---

EDIT 2:

@fgb answer really helped. Thank you very much.

Just added some changes according to [Double-checked_locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) wikipedia site.

my ConfiguracionBase.abreConfiguracion ended up returning an XMLConfiguration object and receives the previous one in order to keep it if the new file name is not found:

```
    protected static XMLConfiguration abreConfiguracion(XMLConfiguration XMLConfig, String configFileName) throws ConfigurationException {
...
        return XMLConfig;
    }
```

And my Specific configuration class has:

```
// Works with acquire/release semantics for volatile
// Broken under Java 1.4 and earlier semantics for volatile
public class Configuracion extends ConfiguracionBase {

    private static volatile Configuracion config = null;
    private static XMLConfiguration XMLConfig = null;
    private static final Object objLock = new Object();

    private Configuracion() {
          // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }

    private Configuracion(String fileName) throws ConfigurationException {
        XMLConfig = abreConfiguracion(XMLConfig, fileName);
    }

    public static Configuracion getInstance() throws ConfigurationException {
        Configuracion result = config;
        if (result == null) {
            synchronized(objLock) {
                result = config;
                if (result == null) {
                    config = result = new Configuracion(configFileName);
                }
            }
        }
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", result.getTimezoneCFD());
        return result;

        /* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking: 
         * Note the local variable result, 
         * which seems unnecessary. This ensures that in cases where helper is already 
         * initialized (i.e., most of the time), the volatile field is only accessed once 
         * (due to "return result;" instead of "return helper;"), which can improve the 
         * method's overall performance by as much as 25 percent.[5] */
    }
...
```

Now everything works just fine.

Again: Tanks.

---

EDIT 3:

Added a comment and changed the return object in getInstance(). Before this I had a mistake so I wasn't doing what [Double-checked_locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) wikipedia site say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't create an instance of `ConfiguracionHolder` so its constructor is not called, and `abreConfiguracion(XMLConfig)` is not called.

I don't think you're getting any benefit from the holder idiom. It's only the static initialization that's thread-safe and that's only run once. If you want to change the `config` instance, then you want to run the configuration multiple times which isn't possible with that idiom.

If you have different threads calling `getInstance()` and `setConfigFileName()` then you'll need some sort of synchronization between them. Making `config` volatile should be enough.

I would move `abreConfiguracion(XMLConfig)` to the constructor of `Configuracion`, make `config` a class variable of `Configuracion`, and make `configFileName` a parameter to the `Configuracion` constructor.

Also, it looks like `abreConfiguracion` should be returning `XMLConfig` instead of taking it as a parameter. Now, it doesn't seem to be setting anything that's visible outside the method.

Comment: Two questions:. 1) setConfigFileName should only set config as null?. Something like this `public static void setConfigFileName(String configFileName) { ConfiguracionBase.configFileName = configFileName; config = null; }`  or should create a new Configuracion. 2) How does it get synchronized with other threads?

Comment: Extending the question number 1: Should I add after the `config = null;` something like this: `Configuracion.getInstance();` ?

Comment: You need the filename to create `config`, so I would create it in the `setConfigFileName` method, leaving `getInstance` to just return `config`. `setConfigFileName` would always create a new instance so it doesn't need double-checked locking, and it's probably called less often so it won't be a bottleneck.