# Initialization-on-demand holder with Android (Dalvik or ART)?

Tags: android, jvm, dalvik

I know Initialization-on-demand holder idiom is great way to implement "Singleton".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

But I'm not sure it is also safe to use in Android (Dalvik or ART).

Only I have found was, it is safe to use on JVM. 
http://literatejava.com/jvm/fastest-threadsafe-singleton-jvm/

Does anybody know about Initialization-on-demand holder idiom is safe on dalvik, or not?

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edited:**

In other word, Does Dalvik and ART guarantees (1) Thread safe, (2) Reentrance and (3) Uniqueness of static member of static inner class?

Comment: see this .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604243/correct-implementation-of-initialization-on-demand-holder-idiom

Comment: @ak sacha, I already read the link you suggested, but I'm not sure that it is fine to use this on Dalvik.

Answer (score 1):

Please find similar answer  it may resolve your queries

[Is Initialization On Demand Holder idiom thread safe without a final modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995036/is-initialization-on-demand-holder-idiom-thread-safe-without-a-final-modifier)

The [class initialization procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) guarantees that if a static field's value is set using a static initializer (i.e. static variable = someValue;) that value is visible to all threads:

Comment: Thank you for answer. In Java Virtual Machine(JVM) world, it is right. But I'm not sure that, it is same on Dalvik Virtual Machine, or Android Runtime virtual machine (ART).